# Not able to get the encrypted password using JFrog Artifactory REST API.

Tags: artifactory

I have written a Java client for calling jfrog api (https://artifactory.abcdcompany.com/artifactory/api/security/encryptedPassword), which can provide the encrypted password.

Option 1:

Process followed for using Basic authentication using username and API Key as below.

1. Created a inputString = "UserName:APIKey"
2. We created a encodedString =  Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(inputString).
3. Created a new String as stringToBeSent = "Basic " + encodedString;
4. We then set the header as Request.setHeader(HTTPHeaders.Authoirization,stringToBeSent);

I am able to connect to the resource and getting a HTTP Status 200. Also, I am getting a response, but in the response, instead of getting the encrypted password, I am receiving the same API Key that I have used in the step 1 above.

Option 2: 
Also, we have tried using the following: 
request.setHeader("X-JFrog-Art-Api", "APIKey"); But no avail. I am receiving the same API Key that am sending.

Should anything be enabled on the serverside to make artifactory respond back with the encrypted password, when called through an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Artifactory does not store passwords internally ([only hashes of passwords](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Users#ManagingUsers-CreatingandEditingUsers)) it cannot 'give' you your encrypted password without you giving it the plain text password.

What really happens in that api is that Artifactory's encryption module is called on the string you send, and it decides wether or not it should be encrypted (based on the structure of the string that gets modified upon encryption) - if yes the string is encrypted and then returned.

Since you're sending an api key which the encryption module knows it will not encrypt it (since there's no point).

The correct way to use that api is to send your plain text password to get it encrypted by the encryption module (since, again, Artifactory does not store user passwords internally).